# Storing csv file contents into multiple arrays

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I have a CSV file that has four columns and multiple rows:

a,b,c,d /n

a,b,c,d /n

I successfully read the contents of the .CSV file and placed them into an ArrayList. How can I separate each column into an array? I want to have arrayA, ArrayB, ArrayC, ArrayD.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(copyUri));
    ArrayList<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String[] record = new String[2];
    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        record = scan.nextLine().split(",");
        records.add(record);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate them into arrays inside the same loop. I would recommend using an ArrayList if you do not know the number of rows in your csv file.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(copyUri));
ArrayList<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] record = new String[2];
ArrayList<String[]> a = new ArrayList<String[]>();
ArrayList<String[]> b = new ArrayList<String[]>();
ArrayList<String[]> c = new ArrayList<String[]>();
ArrayList<String[]> d = new ArrayList<String[]>();

while(scan.hasNext())
{
    record = scan.nextLine().split(",");
    a.add(record[0]);
    b.add(record[1]);
    c.add(record[2]);
    d.add(record[3]);
    records.add(record);
}
```

Another less efficient solution is finding the size of your records list, creating your arrays using this size and populating them with your data.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(copyUri));
ArrayList<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String[] record = new String[2];
while(scan.hasNext()) {
        record = scan.nextLine().split(",");
        records.add(record);
}
int rows = records.size();
String[] a = new String[rows];
String[] b = new String[rows];
String[] c = new String[rows];
String[] d = new String[rows];
int j = 0;
for (String[] temp : records) {
    a[j] = temp[0];
    b[j] = temp[1];
    c[j] = temp[2];
    d[j] = temp[3];
    j++;
}
```

A third idea I got is to initialize your arrays with a certain size (ex: 5) and resize the arrays as you go but I believe this is least efficient since you will have to move elements to the new array every time you resize it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial)' `ColumnProcessor` to do this for you reliably:

```
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();

// To get the values of all columns, use a column processor
ColumnProcessor rowProcessor = new ColumnProcessor();
parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);

//This will kick in our column processor
parser.parse(new FileReader(new File(copyUri)));

//Finally, we can get the column values:
Map<Integer, List<String>> columnValues = rowProcessor.getColumnValuesAsMapOfIndexes();
```

Clean, faster and easier than doing it by hand. This will handle situations such as rows with different number of columns and add `null` to the list instead of throwing exceptions at you.

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).